# Array not loading correctly

Tags: powershell

I have a command that loads a filtered list of servers into a variable:

```
$Computers = Get-adcomputer -filter "OperatingSystem -notlike '*server*'" -properties * |Where-Object {$_.LastLogonDate -gt $time -and ($_.Enabled -eq $true) -and ($_.name -ne 'Rose*')} |select name
```

And I want to use a For each loop to do stuff with those computernames. When I just put the command in I get a list with "name" at the top and a list of computernames

But when I use a Write out the contents of $Computer in loop I get a list of @{name=Computer1}

What is going on? Why can't I get a clean array of computers to work with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every input object piped to `select Name`, it's going to create a new object that has a single property `Name`, with the value copied from the corresponding property on the input object.

To get only the *value* of the `Name` property on the input objects, use `Select-Object`'s `-ExpandProperty` parameter:

```
$Computers = Get-adcomputer -filter "OperatingSystem -notlike '*server*'" -properties * |Where-Object {$_.LastLogonDate -gt $time -and ($_.Enabled -eq $true) -and ($_.name -ne 'Rose*')} |Select -ExpandProperty Name
```

Now, `$computers` will be an array of strings, instead of an array of objects with a `Name` property

Comment: Damn it, I forgot about -ExpandedProperty. That worked, thank you!